# jquery click event get trigged twice on hidden file input

Tags: jquery

i have a list of input files, which is kept hidden from the user. there is a button and on clicking the button the file input get trigged. this button and list of hidden form controls are render on a modal window. on first time its working properly but after saving the data the modal get closed and again i tried adding files the click event is triggered twice. on first selecting the file and select, te file browse come again to select. the code is give below.

```
this._control.button.name = '#fileselector';
....
this._current.fileControl = $('.file-0');
...

$(document)
    .on('click', this._control.button.name, function(event) {
                self._current.fileControl.trigger("click");
            })
    .on()....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unbinding the click event like this

```
$("#buttonid").unbind('click').click(function (e) {    
});
```